# Is there a feature in Krita that allows you to take a picture of your drawing?

Tags: krita, pictures

[image]

I would like to get a full picture of the image. (Including the transparent background and ice cream.) Is there a feature in Krita that allows you to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem hopefully isn't that you haven't found File > Save as or Export, In that case try this:

1. Press Print Screen to get a screenshot to your clipboard.
2. Paste as new image
3. Crop the image to the wanted area.

Comment: "hopefully" LOL,  Although going by the comments, I suspect that is probably the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a custom chequered pattern, and fill a background layer with it. Then export your image as a PNG with the background visible. Just switch off the chequered background layer when you don't need it.

[image]

Or if you'd prefer you can install free screen capture software such as [ShareX](https://getsharex.com/)  which allows you to capture a region of your screen. It's Windows only. Note that a screen capture will only be taken at the resolution of your screen.

Note: I have no affiliation with ShareX

Here's a screenshot of using ShareX to capture a region of the screen. Basically, you hit the ShareX icon in the taskbar, then click and drag a rectangle on your screen to capture a region.

[image]

Comment: I am able to do that in Windows, (I use snipping tool) except what happens when you want to capture it perfectly?

Comment: @WaffleBoots What do you mean by "capture it perfectly"? As far as I know there's no way in Krita to export the transparency check pattern unless you actually make a pattern and fill a layer with it. (see the first part of my answer). The standard transparency check pattern in Krita and other raster image editors such as Photoshop/GIMP is just a visual guide, it's not part of the image.

Comment: What if I had a white background instead?

Comment: @WaffleBoots Then just fill a background layer with white.

Comment: @WaffleBoots you can also try File > Save as or export.

Comment: @user287001 thank you! This works!

Comment: With ShareX, you can actually hit the arrow keys to move your cursor over 1 pixel in that direction when cropping. That, plus using the scroll-wheel to ensure you see the pixel magnifier, lets you do pixel-perfect crops.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, you can't get Krita to export the actual checkered transparent background as checkered, you need to make your own checkers layer or accept that it will be transparent.

With that said, sometimes when asking for feedback or whatnot, it might be slightly inconvenient to export to PNG since you would have to find a place to put the file, name it, then move to where you want it.

In these cases, I prefer doing the following:

1. Flatten the image (Right-click on a layer in the Layers pane and select "Flatten image");
2. Select everything (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>);
3. Copy it to clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);
4. Undo the flattening (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice. First undoes the selection, second undoes the flattening);